# Python audio just makes the windows ding noises

Tags: windows, python-3.x, audio

So, I am using Python3 making something that plays songs. I have it working so if I press 1, it plays the playlist, if I press 2, it plays the first song, and if I press 3, it plays the second song. It works with Circles, but in the playlist once it gets to Bullseye, it just dings (Like when a notification comes up and you click somewhere else) constantly. When you press 3, it dings once and sits there. I think it may be a connection with the song (BullsEye.mp3) is this my code or has anyone else had this issue before?

```
from time import *
import winsound
from winsound import *
input = input('1 for playlist - 2 for Circles - 3 for BullsEye ')
var = int(input)
while var==1:
    winsound.PlaySound("Circles.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
    winsound.PlaySound("BullsEye.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
if var==2:
    winsound.PlaySound("Circles.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
if var==3:
    winsound.PlaySound("BullsEye.mp3", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

Comment: Oh crap, can you change the title? That was from a draft :/

Answer (score 1):

Use `winsound.SND_FILENAME` instead of `winsound.SND_ALIAS` if you want to pass a filename instead of a predefined alias such as `'SystemExit'` otherwise it just plays a default sound if you pass unrecognized alias (that is likely for an arbitrary filename):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

audio_files = ["Circles.wav", "BullsEye.wav"]

def play(filename):
    winsound.PlaySound(filename, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

choice = int(input('1 for playlist - 2 for Circles - 3 for BullsEye '))
if choice == 1:
    for filename in audio_files:
        play(filename)
elif choice in {2, 3}:
    play(audio_files[choice-2])
else:
    assert 0
```

Note: `PlaySound` plays wav files, not mp3. To play mp3 using a default player, you could use `os.startfile()`.